# If statements with multiple ranges (R)

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Does anyone know if its possible to use the base R "ifelse" statement for multiple range conditions at once? Is this easier with dplyr?

```
 If df$var1 < 5 and df$var2 < 5 , then df$var3 = "a" 

If df$var1 > 5 and df$var1<10 AND df$var2>5 and df$var2<10, then df$var3 = "b"

 If df$var1 >10 and df$var2 >10, then df$var3 = "c"
```

Can all this be combined into a single ifelse statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(var3 = case_when(var1 < 5 & var2 < 5 ~ 'a', 
                          var1 > 5 & var1 < 10 & var2 > 5 & var2 < 10 ~ 'b', 
                          var1 >10 & var2 >10 ~ 'c'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Var1 and var2 are numeric variables that sometimes have a value of 0.0000000. In these cases, var3 will become NA. Is there a way to fix this? Thank you

Comment: What value do you want for such cases? You can add the last condition in `case_when` as `TRUE ~ 'new_value'`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I mean, i don't want this to happen. Does R normally recognize 0.00000 to be the same as 0?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can also turn them to integers using `as.integer` so you'll only have 0 instead of 0.00000

Comment: Can you please take a look at this if possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022063/binning-rows-into-ranges-dplyr-r thank you