# "binning" rows into ranges (dplyr/R)

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, range, data-manipulation

I am having a lot of difficulty trying to place rows from a dataset into "bins". For example, suppose I have a data frame "df" with "var1" and "var2" :

[image]

I want to create a new variable called "var3" that follows this logic (R code):

```
1) if var1 <5 and var2<5 .... then var3 = "a"
2) if var1 between (5,10) and var2 between (5,10) .... then var3 = "b"
3) if var1 > 10 and and var2>10 .... then var3 = "c"
```

From a previous question I posted ([If statements with multiple ranges (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020774/if-statements-with-multiple-ranges-r)), I tried the following logic:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(var3 = case_when(var1 < 5 & var2 < 5 ~ 'a', 
                          var1 > 5 & var1 < 10 & var2 > 5 & var2 < 10 ~ 'b', 
                          var1 >10 & var2 >10 ~ 'c'))
```

But when I inspect the df$var3, the logic does not seem to be correct (i.e. some entries for var3 do not have any values. note: the smallest possible value of var1 and va2 is 0).

Can someone please help me?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Sample dataset:

```
a <- rnorm(50,10,10)
b <- rnorm(50, 2,8)

var1 = abs(a)
var2 = abs(b)

df = data.frame(var1, var2)
```

Comment: sure, I will update the question. thank you

Comment: please see the updates. thank you

Comment: Well, your picture are inconsistent with your logic (e.g., picture says var1 > 10 or var2 > 10 then 'c' but your text doesn't).

Comment: @cuttlefish44: i suspected this was probably the problem. i want what is in the picture - can you please help me the write the correct logic to match the picture? thank you for your help

Comment: Use `set.seed` to create random numbers. Tell us which exact line is not generating your expected output in the data i.e what it is giving now vs what it should actually be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(var1 = round(runif(100)*20, 0),
                   var2 = round(runif(100)*20, 0))

df <- df %>% mutate(var3 = ifelse(var1 <= 5 & var2 <= 5, "a", ifelse(var1 <= 10 & var2 <= 10, "b", "c")))
```

to check

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=var1, y= var2, color= var3))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! i am using a computer that has no usb port or internet connection - it only has R with some basic libraries. Unfortunately, I do not have tidyr or tidyverse.  I have dplyr and reshape2. is it possible to modify your answer so that tidyverse is not used? thank you!

Comment: It actually uses dplyr::mutate and ggplot2::ggplot etc functions.  So creating a field(var3) depends on dplyr only.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `case_when`,

```
library(dplyr)

## data make
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(var1 = abs(rnorm(50,10,10)), var2 = abs(rnorm(50,2,8)))

## core
df <- df %>%
  mutate(var3 = case_when(var1 < 5 & var2 < 5 ~ 'a', 
                          var1 < 10 & var2 < 10 ~ 'b',
                          TRUE ~ 'c'))
## plot to check
with(df, plot(var1, var2, col = c(2:4)[as.numeric(as.factor(var3))], cex = 0.7))
abline(h = c(5, 10), v = c(5, 10), lty = 2)
```

[image]